# Manipulate different function and variable

Tags: plotting, manipulate, variable

I have list of functions such that

```
test = {test1[a,x], test2[a,x], test3[a,x]};
```

I would like to plot this three function using manipulation

```
Manipulate[Plot[test[[i]],{x,0,1}],
,{i,{1,2,3}},{a,0,1}]
```

So I want to generate the function by selecting i, but actually it does not respond the manipulate. How shall I solve the issue?

Example

```
f1[x_, x1_] := x^2 + x1^2
f2[x_, x1_] := x^3 + x1
f3[x_, x1_] := x + x1
ftest = {f1[x, x1], f2[x, x1], f3[x, x1]};
Manipulate[Plot[ftest[[i]], {x, -1, 1}], {i, {1, 2, 3}}, {x1, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Instead: `ftest = {f1, f2, f3}; Manipulate[Plot[ftest[[i]][x, x1], {x, -1, 1}], {i, {1, 2, 3}}, {x1, 0, 10}]`. Part (if not all) of the problem is localization of variable `x1` inside `Manipulate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1[x_, x1_] := x^2 + x1^2
f2[x_, x1_] := x^3 + x1
f3[x_, x1_] := x + x1
ftest = {f1, f2, f3};
Manipulate[Plot[ftest[[i]][x, x1], {x, -1, 1}], {i, {1, 2, 3}}, {x1, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, without having to define `ftest`:

```
Manipulate[Plot[f[x, x1], {x, -1, 1}], {f, {f1, f2, f3}}, {x1, 0, 10}]
```